# Reshaping data frame in R according one column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame like this:

```
TargetID        Gene
cg26365299        HOXA9
cg26476852        HOXA9
cg26492446      BHLHE23
cg26521404        HOXA9
cg26531174         CDX1
cg26595643         VAX1
```

And I want it into this shape

```
Gene         TargetID
HOXA9        cg26365299;cg26476852;cg26521404
BHLHE23      cg26492446
CDX1         cg26531174
VAX1         cg26595643
```

I tried with dcast but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Use `aggregate`. Consider `df` is your data.frame:

```
> aggregate(TargetID~Gene, data=df, paste0, collapse=";")
     Gene                         TargetID
1 BHLHE23                       cg26492446
2    CDX1                       cg26531174
3   HOXA9 cg26365299;cg26476852;cg26521404
4    VAX1                       cg26595643
```

Comment: @user976991 glad to be useful, you can accept the answer if it helps you to solve your problem/question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility.

```
ll <- lapply(unstack(df), paste0, collapse = ";")
data.frame(TargetID = names(ll), Gene = unlist(ll), row.names = NULL)

#   TargetID                             Gene
# 1  BHLHE23                       cg26492446
# 2     CDX1                       cg26531174
# 3    HOXA9 cg26365299;cg26476852;cg26521404
# 4     VAX1                       cg26595643
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `plyr`:

```
ddply(df,.(Gene),summarise,TargetID=paste(TargetID,collapse=";"))
  Gene                         TargetID
1 BHLHE23                       cg26492446
2    CDX1                       cg26531174
3   HOXA9 cg26365299;cg26476852;cg26521404
4    VAX1                       cg26595643
```